# Чем заменить php-функцию apache_request_headers() чтобы прочитать свой собственный HTTP-заголовок из запроса?

Tags: php, apache, http, header, веб-сервер

PHP-скрипту в запросе передается мой собственный HTTP-заголовок: **X-Data-Token**

Как в php-скрипте его прочитать, если функция **apache_request_headers()** на сервере не доступна, а в массиве **$_SERVER** он естественно не появляется.

Comment: А как на счет функции get_headers ? Она тоже молчит?

Comment: Так она же судя по описанию делает не то что мне нужно: "возвращает все заголовки из ответа сервера на HTTP-запрос". Мне на сервере нужны HTTP-заголовки не ответа сервера, а запроса клиента.

Comment: Тогда, кроме как обратиться к getallheaders - но она псевдоним apache_request_headers, вы сказали, без нее. То кроме как $_SERVER, который у вас также приходит пустой, ничем другим вернуть не получится. Если только еще попробовать глянуть в сторону socket и писать отдельный поток, самого запроса от клиента.

Comment: А почему у вас нет доступа к этой функции? Не хватает версии PHP? Может, стоит обновиться?

Comment: На хостинге стоит: PHP - 5.3.3, в режиме FastCGI, а согласно документации: php.net/manual/ru/function.apache-request-headers.php, поддержка данной функции в PHP с режимом FastCGI доступна только начиная с версии 5.4.0. Потому наверное мне или версию PHP обновить или переключить PHP в режим модуля Apache или CGI.

Comment: Кстати в комментах к документации: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.apache-request-headers.php пишут что можно еще попробовать пошаманить в .htaccess, в плане добавления в него: RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_X_DATA_TOKEN:%{HTTP:X-Data-Token}]